# xml2 installed but not found during compilation

Tags: libraries, make

I'm trying to compile the lib https://github.com/bjz/gl-rs.

I'm getting an error when running make:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
(a long list of linker args follows)
note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
```

If I'm reading this right, the linker cannot find the lib xml2. I made sure xml2 and libxml2 are installed (via sudo apt-get install) but that's not enough.

What to do?

Comment: Did you install `libxml2-dev` or just `libxml2`? usually it is the `-dev` package that provides the libraries and headers required for building

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Ubuntu packaging system, the `libXXX` packages often only contain the runtime libraries necessary for running applications that dynamically link the library.

In order to get the libraries and header files necessary for compiling and building, there is usually a separate `libXXX-dev` package (`-dev` indicating that the packages are for *development*). You can check what development packages are available for a particular library using the `apt-cache` search engine e.g.

```
apt-cache search devel | grep libxml2
```

In your case, you are probably missing the `libxml2-dev` package.

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful to find the package:

```
sudo yum provides /usr/lib64/libxml2.a
```

and this to install it:

```
sudo yum install libxml2-static
```

(I'm aware you are using apt, but I came across this post while looking for solution using yum)